# Make Access Inputbox Alert

Tags: microsoft-access, alert

I have an access macro that imports some data and sets a certain field to a value I give it in an inputbox, and I was wondering if there is a way to make the input box alert like I have my message boxes doing.

Eg. when after all the process is complete I have the Messagebox that alerts and therefore makes the taskbar flash, so that I know it's done even if I moved away from it. Does anyone know of a way to do this with an inputbox?

Comment: I have thought of a workaround: just do an alert messagebox right before opening the inputbox, and that works fine, but I'm looking to find out if there is a solution that wouldn't require an extra keypress. This process already takes about 10 messageboxes and inputboxes worth of stuff to to through

Comment: If you want the taskbar icon to flash look up the API procedure call to do that in VBA.